# is there any simple way to do localization (l10n)

Tags: java, localization

I have an existing system and I need to do localization. It is having mainly two part-
    1. log message (using log4j)
    2. front end is jsp

for the first one, i can use java.util.ResourceBundle and read corresponding message.properties file and for the second one I can use JSTL. But these required lots of code change (more than 1000 files). Is there any other way to achieve this? For example

```
private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(MyClass.class); 

public int executeCmd() {
    log.info("Executing command");
}
```

Can java  "do some magic" and allow me to hook my class in log4j and allow me get access "Executing command" string so that I can do the necessary l10n stuff in one place (may be using ResourceBundle)?

Thanks in advances

Dipankaj

Comment: There won't be any magic, you'll have to do that yourself...

Comment: thanks fge, if so how can i do that?